# SqlBulkCopy Slow inserting with async (from Oracle to SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to do an insert into SQL Server from Oracle using `SqlBulkCopy`, but it is too slow.

Here are some details:

- SQL Server 2014 with recovery model "Simple" (clean database for this).
- Destination SQL Server table with 30 columns as follows:

Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DestinationTable]
(
    [PROJECT_NUMBER] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [PROJECT_ID] [float] NULL,
    [PROJECT_NAME] [nvarchar](240) NULL,
    [TASK_NUMBER] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [TASK_NAME] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [EMPLOYEE_SUPPLIER_NAME] [nvarchar](240) NULL,
    [EMPLOYEE_SUPPLIER_NUMBER] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_TYPE] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [GL_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [GL_PERIOD_NAME] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PA_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID] [numeric](15, 0) NOT NULL,
    [EXP_CAT] [nchar](11) NULL,
    [BILLABLE_FLAG] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [LINE_TYPE] [nchar](7) NULL,
    [REV_HOURS] [float] NULL,
    [BILL_RATE] [float] NULL,
    [BILL_AMOUNT] [numeric](22, 5) NULL,
    [ACCRUED_REVENUE] [numeric](22, 5) NOT NULL,
    [AR_INV_NUM] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [AP_INVOICE_NUM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EXPENDITURE_COMMENT] [nvarchar](240) NULL,
    [PROJECT_BILL_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
    [PROJECT_CURRENCY_CODE] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PROJFUNC_CURRENCY_CODE] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PROJFUNC_REVENUE_AMOUNT] [numeric](22, 5) NOT NULL,
    [PROJFUNC_BILL_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
    [PROJECT_REVENUE_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
    [BILL_HOLD_FLAG] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Methods:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Start");

    string oracleConnectionString =
                "Data Source=/*Datasource*/; ";
    string sql = "Select * From OriginTable)";

    var dt = GetDataTableAsync(oracleConnectionString, sql);

    await InsertDataAsync(dt);

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    int timeSpan = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Seconds;

    Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString() + " Seconds in total for operation");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

GetDataTable:

```
private static IDataReader GetDataTableAsync(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reading from Oracle started");
    var startTimeOracle = DateTime.Now;

    var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();

    var command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    Console.WriteLine("Reading from Oracle finished");
    Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - startTimeOracle).Seconds + " seconds to retrieve from Oracle");

    return reader;
}
```

InsertDataAsync:

```
private static async Task InsertDataAsync(IDataReader dt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Writing to SQL Server started");
    var startTimeSqlServer = DateTime.Now;

    string sql = "Truncate table DestinationTable;" + Environment.NewLine;
    string connectionString = /*ConnectionString*/;

    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null))
    {
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
        bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1000;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTable";

        await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dt);

        Console.WriteLine("Writing to SQL Server finished");
        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - startTimeSqlServer).Seconds + " seconds to copy into SQL Server");
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Text output:

```
Start
Reading from Oracle started
Reading from Oracle finished
4 Seconds to retrieve from Oracle
Writing to SQL Server started
Writing to SQL Server finished
42 Seconds to copy into SQL Server
Finished
47 Seconds in total for operation
```

(For reference, this is 14.6K rows with 30 columns).

I have tried from different recommendations to use DbDataReader instead of IDataReader, I have also tried with OracleDataReader, I didn't see difference between these.

I also tried running with synchronous transaction, and I changed several batch sizes (100, 1000, 10000, 20000) with no noticeable difference

`DestinationTable` doesn't have indexes of constraints and for reference running the query using openquery:

```
insert into DestinationTable  
    select * 
    from openquery(LinkedServer, 'select * from OriginTable')
```

takes 25 seconds

Anything I could be missing? I'm looking to be running several of these queries so I'm looking to have it as fast as possible. (It wouldn't be the best approach to lock the table but if it's the only option can be done)

Comment: As a side note, some of those columns being `float`s seems questionable choices. `PROJECT_REVENUE_AMOUNT`, for example, implies a monetary amount, and base 2 numbers are money are a terrible mix.

Comment: good tip, what would you recommend to use please? Decimal?  (I'm consuming from an Oracle DB and I don't have the exact definition from it)

Comment: This table has potentially very wide rows, which leads me to wonder if network throughput is you constraining bottleneck.  Have you measured this?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I haven't done a proper test (don't know how) but I did created a local database in my dev computer and ran it there, the performance was quite similar, however I do understand my test wasn't the best to confirm it

Comment: Why do you need a `truncate table` if you have a "clean database", as you say? Does that "clean" indicate "empty" (e.g. no rows)? Then a truncate table would be pointless and just wasting compute cycles...

Comment: A `decimal` would be a far better choice, yes @Baldie47 .

Comment: @marc_s because I'm testing it over and over and when this gets rolled will be truncating the table before inserting. the only table the DB has is this one that I created to receive the insert

Comment: OK - but just for the sake of argument - can you test against a truly empty database, and skipping the `truncate table` ? Is that taking up the bulk of the execution time?

Comment: @marc_s I have just tried it and got the same performance (to note, before running it I do truncate the table manually to not affect it)  but doing it without the truncate statement in the c# script renders the same result

Comment: @Larnu I changed the floats to decimal (18,2) but the performance didn't actually change (I could make them smaller, but doesn't look like the big issue is that one)

Comment: I didn't say it would affect the performance, @Baldie47 .

Comment: @Larnu sorry I misunderstood, however I do appreciate your comment, and changed accordingly